# Is the Poincare polynomial a fundamental object?

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Consider a surface $S$ whose homology is $H_*(S)$. At least for sufficiently nice surfaces, whatever this vague adjective means, one can calculate the Betti number (or Hodge numbers) and find the dimensions of the homology groups. Then it is easy to construct the Poincare polynomial. For example, for the torus we have $b_1=1, b_2=2, b_3=1$ and thus $P(T^1)=x+2x^2+x^3$.

My questions is wether this polynomial is in some sense fundamental. Are there examples where one cannot directly calculate Betti numbers but can find the Poincare polynomial and as such find out the dimensions of the homology groups? And if so what is the (or a) method to calculate the Poincare polynomial?

Comment: I can think of two ways off the bat where this comes in handy. First is that in Morse theory, we have, letting $M_t(f)$ be the counting function, that $M_t(f)-P_t(M)=(1+t)R(t)$ for some remainder term $R$. If the Morse function is perfect, we actually have $M_t(f)=P_t(M)$. An example whereI have every seen done is in [this](http://www.math.toronto.edu/mgualt/Morse%20Theory/Atiyah-Bott.pdf) paper of Atiyah-Bott. They are studying the solution space of a paticular differential equation on surfaces, and they do so via Morse theory, and careful application of these things allows them to compute.

Comment: The other is that in practice, it can be very easy to reconstruct a polynomial with its values. In particular some simple things can be said. For a manifold of dimension $n$, say oriented, connected and compact, there are $[(n-1)/2]$ independant cohomology dimensions (thanks to Poincare duality). Now for a generic choice of coefficents, we have that with $[(n-1)/2]$ values of the function, we can reconstruct $P_t(M)$! In particular, the Euler characteristic $\chi(M)=P_t(M)(-1)$ is sufficent fo $dim(M)\le 2$, and $\chi(M)$ and $dim(H^*(M))$ is sufficent for $dim(M)\le 4$, which can (cont.)

Comment: computed for certian spaces with structure theorems. This analysis rarely goes under this title though, and is rather treated as a sequence of linear equalities. I will note though, I don't think this makes $P_t(M)$ more fundemental than any other organizational tool.

Comment: The Kunneth formula becomes very simple with Poincare polynomials, so that may be computationally more helpful. I'd like to know if there's any deeper fundamental significance of it.

Comment: Serre ingeniously used Poincaré polynomials for Eilenberg-MacLane spaces to prove that simply-connected CW complexes which are not contractible have a $\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb Z_2$ summand in $\pi_i(X)$ for infinitely many $i$.